# Chef-solo - what are the correct permissions for "backup" folder?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm running chef-solo which uses the [wordpess cookbook](https://github.com/brint/wordpress-cookbook). The cookbook downloads wordpress .tar.gz to `backup` directory (specified by `file_backup_path` in `solo.rb`), `chown`s it to `www-data` and then runs `tar` extract as user `www-data`. This means it assumes that `backup` folder (and all folders above it) are accessible by the `www-data` user. In fact, by any user that will be specified in appropriate attributes.

I'm trying to understand whether really `backup` folder should be read-accessible by anyone or the cookbook should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The cookbook actually uses the [tar](https://github.com/gofullstack/tar-cookbook) cookbook for downloading and extracting the file.

The resource exposed by this cookbook in fact defaults to using the backup direcort to download the files, which is a rather bad choice. In fact, the backup directory should generally have rather strict access permissions as it can contain sensitive files containing passwords and other stuff.

A more sensible default would be the cache path, accessible with `Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]`. To quote the documentation:

> The location in which cookbooks (and other transient data) files are stored when they are synchronized. (This value can also be used in recipes to download files with the `remote_file` resource.)